# Flask wsgi python Import Error: no module named catalog

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, wsgi

i have been following along with tutorials from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps#step-five-%E2%80%93-create-the-wsgi-file) and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/) to set up a flask wsgi python application served on ubuntu amazon lightsail, and i'm getting the following error:

error

```
[Tue Jul 25 16:09:14.573839 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19081:tid 140056986322688] [remote 65.102.85.13:26759]     from catalog import app as application
[Tue Jul 25 16:09:14.573903 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19081:tid 140056986322688] [remote 65.102.85.13:26759] ImportError: No module named catalog
[Tue Jul 25 18:11:00.019707 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 19082:tid 140056977929984] [client 91.196.50.33:42031] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/
```

this is my current file structure

```
root@:/var/www/catalog# ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  .
drwxr-xr-x  ..
drwxr-xr-x  catalog
drwxr-xr-x  catalog.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  catalog.wsgi
-rw-r--r--  setup.py
```

and

```
root@:/var/www/catalog/catalog# ls -la
total 120
drwxr-xr-x .
drwxr-xr-x ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 client_secrets.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 database_setup.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 fb_client_secrets.json
drwxr-xr-x 8 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 lotsofmenus.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 lotsofmenususers.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 restaurant_menu_app.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 restaurantmenu.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 restaurantmenuwithusers.db
drwxr-xr-x 4 static
drwxr-xr-x 2 templates
drwxr-xr-x 6 venv
```

my python.wsgi file
import sys

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/catalog")

from catalog import app as application
application.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
```

my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/catalog.config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 52.34.254.190
    ServerAlias ec2-52-34-254-190.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    ServerAdmin admin@52.34.254.190
    WSGIDaemonProcess catalog python-path=/var/www/catalog:/var/www/catalog/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup catalog
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/catalog/catalog.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/catalog/catalog/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/catalog/catalog/static
    <Directory /var/www/catalog/catalog/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='catalog',
    packages=['catalog'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'flask',
    ],
)
```

i can get my virtual env running, but my broswer ip is still getting a 500 internal server error. I can't figure out why the module isn't found, what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by changing the main app file to `__init__.py`